# Way to flip sort order of items in div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a list of notes that are being posted to a view from a model and being posted to the page

```
 <div id="listResults"></div>
 <div class="pam bgpage line" id="navResults"></div>
<script id="listTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-template">
<div class="clearfix ptl phl modalRow">
<div class="ui ui_std_${Type} activity_icon"></div>
<div class="activity">
    <p class="activity_head">${SubType} ${Type}</p>
    <span class="activity_detail">${CreatedDuration} by ${CreatedBy}</span><br />
    <div class="activity_wrap">
        {{html Note}}
    </div>
</div>
 </div>
</script>
<script id="navTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-template">
<div class="unit size1of5 lastUnit">
    {{if TotalItemCount>0}}
    <label class="dgray mlm mrs">1 - ${LastItemOnPage} of ${TotalItemCount}</label>
    {{else}}No Recent Activity{{/if}}
</div>
 </script>
```

These notes are being posted in a descending order i want to make a javascript or jquery function that would take a button onclick and flip the order to ascending. Is there a way to do taht easily?  I cannot find an answer.

Comment: Easily - nope. You need to write the code to re-write that portion of the DOM.

Comment: Start by adding a property to the label called `data-total`. Get all the label elements (not sure what the unique classname for the containint div would be). Sort them and then add them again to the div in the sorted order

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, need to add the sort value to the div containing the data you would like to sort and wrap all the articles in a container div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="button" id="test" value="sort"/>
   <div id="activitycontent">
       <div class="activity" data-sort="22">
           <span>22</span>
       </div>
       <div class="activity" data-sort="11">
           <span>11</span>
       </div>
       <div class="activity" data-sort="33">
           <span>33</span>
       </div>
   </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var direction = 1;
        function sortHelper(a, b) {
            // this can be made faster if you pre store these values
            // retuns 1,-1 or 0 to sort the array of div elements
            // using the value of the attribute data-sort
            vala = a.getAttribute("data-sort");
            valb = b.getAttribute("data-sort");
            ret = vala>valb?1:(vala<valb)?-1:0;
            // multiply by direction (ascending descending)
            return ret * direction;
        }
        $("#test").on("click", null, null, function () {
            // sort opposite of previously used direction.
            direction = direction * -1;
            // get array of html Div elements containing the article
            var divArr = Array.prototype.slice.call
                ($("#activitycontent div.activity"), 0);
            var i = 0;
            var container = document.getElementById("activitycontent");
            // sort the articles based on data-sort property
            divArr.sort(function (a, b) {
                return sortHelper(a, b);
            });
            // add the div elements containing the articles in the right order
            for (i = divArr.length-1;i>-1;i--){
                container.appendChild(divArr[i]);
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you had them posted in a table rather than in divs, and the thing you were sorting on was one of the columns, the jquery tablesorter plugin would hook you right up.  It's a good one to learn anyway.

Alternate option - if you have enough control over your model, you could post them twice, once in the initial order, once in reverse order.  Have the reverse order version start out hidden, and then when you press the button, use jQuery's `.show()` and `.hide()` to swap which is visible.

Alternate option - if you don't have that level of control over your model, you can use jquery to iterate through the list of divs once the apge is loaded, grab the list of notes with a selector, and then use `.each()`, `.clone()` and `.insertBefore()` to populate your reversed list, and then use the show/hide button as before.

I hope you find this helpful.